# Async ObservableCollection from Interface in C# (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, interface

I've got an `ObservableCollection` in an interface and I'm using it with a `RestApi-Request`. It has some Await functions and it must be async. But there's an error.

Here's the interface:

```
public interface IDbConnection
{
    ObservableCollection<Einkauf> GetEinkauf();
}
```

Here's the part from the class it is using:

```
public partial class RestView : IDbConnection
{
    private ObservableCollection<Einkauf> _einkauf;
    private const string Url = "http://localhost:3003/einkauf";
    private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public RestView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    public async ObservableCollection<Einkauf> GetEinkauf()
    {
        var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
        var einkauf = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Einkauf>>(content);
        _einkauf = new ObservableCollection<Einkauf>(einkauf);
        speisenListe.ItemsSource = _einkauf;
        return _einkauf;
    }

}
```

The `GetEinkauf` is underlined and it says:

```
CS1983 C# The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `GetEinkauf` is supposed to be implemented as an asynchronous method, you should change it return type to `Task<ObservableCollection<Einkauf>>` and also change its name to GetEinkauf**Async** to follow the naming convention for asynchronous methods:

```
public interface IDbConnection
{
    Task<ObservableCollection<Einkauf>> GetEinkaufAsync();
}

public async Task<ObservableCollection<Einkauf>> GetEinkaufAsync()
{
    var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
    var einkauf = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Einkauf>>(content);
    _einkauf = new ObservableCollection<Einkauf>(einkauf);
    speisenListe.ItemsSource = _einkauf;
    return _einkauf;
}
```

You could then `await` the method from any method marked as `async`:

```
var collection = await GetEinkaufAsync();
```

If another class implements the `IDbConnection` interface in a synchronous fashion for some reason, it could use the `Task.FromResult` method to return a `Task<ObservableCollection<Einkauf>>`:

```
public class SomeOtherClass : IDbConnection
{
    public Task<ObservableCollection<Einkauf>> GetEinkaufAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new ObservableCollection<Einkauf>());
    }
}
```

Comment: one thing is missing:
            return 'await' Task.FromResult(_einkauf);

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface IDbConnection
{
    Task<ObservableCollection<Einkauf>> GetEinkauf();
}

public async Task<ObservableCollection<Einkauf>> GetEinkauf()
{
  ...
}
```